# How to determine whether a set is a star domain

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis

I have the two sets

> $A_1=\mathbb{C}\backslash\{\text{line segment between $1+i$ and $1-i$}\}$,
>   $A_2=\mathbb{C}\backslash\{z\in\mathbb{R}_{\leq0}\text{ or }z=ai,a\in[0,1]\}$.

I have to determine which is of these can be a star domain and which an elementary.

**What I know**
A star domain has a point such that for all points in that domain, the line segment between the star point and the other point is contained in the domain.
Of course this leads me to think that the domains above are not star domains, since they are $\mathbb{C}$ with a line (segment) missing. However I would not know how to prove this formally.

Further, an elementary domain is a domain $D$ such that for all piecewise smooth curve $g\in D$ and all functions $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, we have $\int_gf(x)=0$. I see this as the 'domains without holes'. Because $A_1$ and $A_2$ have holes, I think that they aren't elementary either.
But again, how would I prove this?

Comment: Hint for the first question. In each case imagine that the missing points are solid and a light at a possible star point and show that there are some points in the shadow. As an instructor I'd be satisfied by a geometric proof that considered two ways you might try to place the star. - no algebra needed. Hint for the second question: can you really surround some missing points by a closed curve in both cases? I hope no one jumps in with an answer before you get a chance to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: @EthanBolker For the first question: That's exactly how I imagined it as well! :) But what do you mean by geometric proof? Like a drawing? Because I dont think that will be accepted. For the second: In the first case I can, but in the second not.

Comment: Notice that if there were a point $z \in A_1$ satisfying your definition, then you could connect it with the same point reflected through $1$ using a line segment. Is this possible?

Comment: A good picture for each typical case would convince me that you understood. I don't know how much formality your instructor requires - can you ask? For the second part of the question - if you can't draw such a curve then the domain has no holes so is elementary.